# GCP logging console doesn't display some GKE log messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

I have K8S cluster in GCP (version is **1.20.8-gke.900** from the regular update channel).
All cluster pods write logs in **STDOUT** or **STDERR** from Docker containers.

I found that some log messages never appear in GCP Logging console.

For example:

```
{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "timestamp": "2021-08-18T09:38:34.016614425Z",
  "caller": "dbscan/dbscan.go:82",
  "message": "Query",
  "method": "GET",
  "uri": "/api/v1/test",
  "path": "/api/v1/test",
  "correlation-id": "2021435824-1629279514010580579-448",
  "rowCount": 4,
  "pid": 679135,
  "sql": "SELECT id FROM test WHERE name = ANY($1::varchar[])",
  "args": [
    [
      "aaa",
      "bbb",
      "ccc",
      "ddd"
    ]
  ],
  "time": 3282419,
  "logging.googleapis.com/labels": {},
  "logging.googleapis.com/sourceLocation": {
    "file": "/go/pkg/mod/github.com/georgysavva/scany@v0.2.4/dbscan/dbscan.go",
    "line": "82",
    "function": "github.com/georgysavva/scany/dbscan.processRows"
  }
}
```

However, I can see the above message in GKE console via **kubectl** utility.

Also, I can see below log message in GCP Logging:

```
{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "timestamp": "2021-08-18T09:41:48.695923055Z",
  "caller": "puddle@v1.1.1/pool.go:470",
  "message": "Dialing PostgreSQL server",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "logging.googleapis.com/labels": {},
  "logging.googleapis.com/sourceLocation": {
    "file": "/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jackc/puddle@v1.1.1/pool.go",
    "line": "470",
    "function": "github.com/jackc/puddle.(*Pool).constructResourceValue"
  }
}
```

I can't understand what prevents this message to be displayed in GCP Logging console...

Comment: If there are no logs at all, then maybe a permission or SA issue. If specifics logs are missing, did you enable system,workloads logs? MENU>GKE>cluster>Features> cloud logging. Try in legacy and upgraded view any difference?

Comment: In GKE console: Cloud Operations for GKE -> System and workload logging and monitoring.


And yes, I can see all other messages, e.g.:

{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "timestamp": "2021-08-18T09:41:48.695923055Z",
  "caller": "puddle@v1.1.1/pool.go:470",
  "message": "Dialing PostgreSQL server",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "logging.googleapis.com/labels": {},
  "logging.googleapis.com/sourceLocation": {
    "file": "/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jackc/puddle@v1.1.1/pool.go",
    "line": "470",
    "function": "github.com/jackc/puddle.(*Pool).constructResourceValue"
  }
}

Comment: @dany-l, looks like I can see some messages in legacy GCP Logging view... Any ideas why it doesn't display them in the new view?

Comment: Legacy monitoring is [not supported on 1.2](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/migration), so it is possible you looking at old logs

Comment: also when looking at logs, make sure you looking at k8s_container and not gke_container.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at `k8s_container`...

Comment: Then open a support case at MENU or https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers, maybe a bug.

Comment: Can you check which version of fluentbit used in logging. This is known issue with GKE where some logs are not logged by fluentbit 1.3.0.

Comment: Hi @jyothi-kiranmayi, gke.gcr.io/fluent-bit:v1.5.7-gke.1 and gke.gcr.io/fluent-bit-gke-exporter:v0.16.2-gke.0

Comment: From the GKE logs that are appearing on Cloud logging, does any of the logs have the "jsonpayload.time" field?

Comment: Some of them have jsonpayload.timestamp (e.g.: timestamp: "2021-08-25T03:54:08.679289208Z"), but not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried reproducing, and could get the JSON snippet to log regularly once I removed the “time” field(not “timestamp”). I suspect the format of value in the “time” field("time": 3282419) mismatch is causing the logs from not getting generated on Cloud logging.  Refer [Time-related fields](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration#timestamp-processing) for information.